# header () in php not downloading the file

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read the file from php and downloading it from the ui on click of  a button

```
<?php
$file = 'download.csv'; //path to the file on disk


if (file_exists($file)) {

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contact-list.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
    //unlink($file);

    exit;
}

else {

    print "file not found!!!";
}
?>
```

But the file is not getting downloaded. No error, the code is working. unlink() function deleted the file.

Comment: is download.csv in the same directory as this script and if so do its permissions / ownership allow for it to be access by the webserver?

Comment: What are the headers when you open this page manually in your browser?

Comment: yeah same folder only.

Comment: Try echo readfile($file);

Comment: hey actually the page works if i give the full url. But in my code i am calling this page from other page like this. header("csv-download.php");

csv-download.php has the code given above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my comment answers yes to all, then the only think i see that might be an issue.

application/csv

Should be:

text/csv